# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am facing error "PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large" difficulty in passing array "record" from the below mentioned code in React js to node js backend.

```
const [record, setRecord] = useState([]);

const handleClick = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/books", record);
        navigate("/");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setError(true)
      }
    };

return (
    <CSVReader
      onUploadAccepted={(results: any) => {
        console.log('---------------------------');
        var column = results.data.map((row)=>{
          return row[8]
        });
        console.log(column);
        setRecord([ ...record, column ]);
        //console.log(results);
        console.log('---------------------------');
      }}
    >
)
```

My Node Js code is as follow

```
app.post("/books", (req, res) => {
  const values = [
    req.body.record
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your backend code. If you use Express.js with some body parsers, you can increase body limit, like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
```

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr this resolved my issue.